# SAS - Input all variables in a data step without naming every variable

Tags: sas, user-input

How does one input all variables/columns within a data step using `INPUT` but without naming every variable? This can be done by naming each variable, for example:

```
DATA dataset;
    INFILE '/folders/myfolders/file.txt';
    INPUT variable1 variable2 variable3 variable4 $ variable5;
RUN;
```

However, this is very tedious for large datasets containing 200+ variables.

Comment: So you really have a SAS dataset already?  That is what the `sas7bdat` extension means.

Comment: Text files have no way to store metadata. How is SAS supposed to know what names you want to use for the variables if you don't tell it? You can use `proc import` and SAS will guess at what is supposed to be in the file by looking at the values.

Comment: Do you have a record layout or metadata file? If so, you can use that to create the INPUT statement. If not, you can use PROC IMPORT, but it guesses, and is sometimes wrong.

Comment: Have you tried `input var1-var4 $ var5;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original question implied that you already had a SAS data set. In that case all variables are automatically included when you SET the dataset.

```
data copy ;
  set '/folders/myfolders/file.sas7bdat';
run;
```

Or just reference it in the analysis you want to do.

```
proc means data='/folders/myfolders/file.sas7bdat';
run;
```

If you actually have a TEXT file and you want to read it into a SAS dataset you could use `PROC IMPORT` to guess what is in the file.  If it has a header row then proc import will try to convert those into valid variable names.  It will also try to guess how to define the variables based on what values it sees in the text file.

```
proc import out=want datafile='/folders/myfolders/file.txt' dbm=dlm ;
  delimiter=',';
run;
```

Or if the issue that it is too hard to create 200 unique variable names you could just use a variable list with numeric suffixes to save a lot of typing.

```
DATA dataset;
  INFILE '/folders/myfolders/file.txt' dsd ;
  length var1-var200 $20 ;
  input var1-var200 ;
RUN;
```

Comment: I may want to download a dataset to a different libname. However, all of this is missing the point of my question. I’ll change my example to “.txt”

Comment: If the text file has column headers then PROC IMPORT can use the column headers to guess what variable names you want to use.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I see that there isn't an easy way to use `INPUT` to input all variables - at least without common var names (var1-var200) or macros. But you have provided many ways around this - thank you Tom